# Implement destructor/dispose in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  use asp net 4.5.

I have Marker.aspx page and code behind page Marker.aspx.cs.
Whenever postback occurred `Page_Load` function is fired in code behind and GeoMarkup class created.

```
   GeoMarkup markupManager;       
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         markupManager = new GeoMarkup("constans",
                                        "mapName",
                                        null);

    }
```

Whenever postback is implemented I need destructor to be fired and put inside destructor this row:

```
markupManager.Dispose();
```

My question is how can I implement destructor in code behind?;

Comment: I think you should use `Page_Unload` instead: *The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. At this point, page properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and cleanup is performed.* With the page sent to the client you it should be safe to clean up all required resources.

Comment: can't you use garbage collector? I highly recommend you not to implement dispose because of some cases which may happen which can deprecate your code. the better equivalent ,which still is not very nice, can be calling garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Your code behind class is a subclass of [`Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a virtual `Dispose` method.

You should override that method in your code behind

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    if (markupManager != null) {
        markupManager.Dispose();
        markupManager = null;
    }
}
```

The HTTP pipeline will call Dispose on classes when they are no longer needed for the processing of the current HTTP request.